# Java - ArrayList add doesn't add the element, set doesn't replace existing, just delete

Tags: java, arraylist

Code:

```
System.out.println("Size inside upd: " + size());
list.remove(index);
System.out.println("Size inside upd: " + size());
list.add(index, element);
System.out.println("Size inside upd: " + size());
```

Output:

```
7
6
6
```

Another variant:

```
System.out.println("Size inside upd: " + size());
list.set(index, element);
System.out.println("Size inside upd: " + size());
```

Output:

```
7
6
```

Why? I don't understand the reason. index == 0, element is an object of a custom class, not null. I think I did something wrong. I want to replace, but it's deleted

Comment: Yes Ivan Please read the javadoc for remove. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) the link. If you pass an int it will consider it as index. You need to pass an object to remove that specific object.

Comment: I want to replace the item

Comment: To replace you need to use add with index click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) for explanation. Then remove the old object with index + 1.

Comment: @kuporific How would a set help ?

Comment: @StackFlowed, in docs written that it shifts all elements, but I want to replace. I even tried use just list.add(element), but the sizes before and after the same

Comment: Oops, sorry. I used size(), it's a method of my class, but not list.size(), which works correct. The question is solved.